# Scrollbar position is not retained when we moved from one pop up window to another pop up

Tags: javascript

I have one .aspx page, from this page i am opening a popwindow using

```
window.open("..Something.aspx?id=" + objThis, "POPUP1", "width=700,height=450,left=50,top=50, scrollbars=yes").
```

It will open new pop window "POPUP1" .With Scrollbar is enabled,now i scroll down the window, click on link which will open another popup window. But problem is scrollbar of first popup window "POPUP1" is set back to top. is there any alternative way to retain the scroll position "POPUP1"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably means that your link is using `href="#"` like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open(...)">
```

If so, change it to:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="window.open(...)">
```

It won't set the scrollbar back to the top of the page that way.